# Finding matrix C given A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two matrices where $A = $ \begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\-1&3\end{bmatrix} and $B =$ \begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}. The question asks to Solve for the matrix C (i.e. find matrix C):
$$(((AB^T)^{-1})^TB)^T= 2C + B$$

I have done the calculations by following the formula and get \begin{bmatrix}3&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}. However that dosen't equal the right hand side of the formula so my question is 
a. Is my answer correct? and 
b. Is there a easier way to do this then by calculating each part of the formula by using logic?

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
(((AB^T)^{-1})^TB)^T
= B^T ((AB^T)^{-1})
= B^T \left(B^T\right)^{-1} A^{-1}
= A^{-1}.
$$
So you have 
$$
A^{-1} = 2C+B
$$
and hence
$$
C = \frac{A^{-1}-B}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

There are a few very useful identities that you should swear on your life to never forget. Ready?
$$(AB)^T = B^T A^T$$
$$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$$
$$(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$$
In summary, when we "distribute" the "transpose" or "inverse" over a product, we need to reverse the order of the product. We can also interchange the order in which we invert or take the transpose.

Now, starting with
$$(((AB^T)^{-1})^TB)^T = 2C + B$$
We first apply the transpose on the LHS
$$B^T((AB^T)^{-1})^ = 2C + B$$
Apply the inverse,
$$B^T({B^T}^{-1} A^{-1})^ = 2C + B$$
Then
$$A^{-1} = 2C +B$$
How beautiful is that? Observe that $A = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 1 & -2 \\ -1 & -3 \end{array} \right] \Rightarrow A^{-1} = \frac{1}{5} \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 3 & -2 \\ -1 & -1 \end{array} \right]$
Hence,
$$2C = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 0 & -1 \\ 2 & -2 \end{array} \right] - \frac{1}{5} \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 3 & -2 \\ -1 & -1 \end{array} \right]$$
$$2C = \frac{1}{5} \left[ \begin{array}{c c} -3 & -3 \\ 11 & -9 \end{array} \right]$$
$$C = \frac{1}{10} \left[ \begin{array}{c c} -3 & -3 \\ 11 & -9 \end{array} \right]$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Will do my best to remember these formulas.